# Read-only input in Android Webkit not working

Tags: javascript, android, keyboard, webkit, readonly-attribute

I have a text input field in my web page that I am using to collect a date (via the jQuery Tools .dateinput). The user does not need to be able to type into the field. A dialog box appears when the field is clicked on. This is a problem on my Motorola Droid, because I don't want the soft-keyboard to appear when the field is clicked.

I have tried input.blur() on focus and also setting the field to disabled and readonly. Setting the field to disabled has undesired side effects. Setting the field to readonly works in everything but the Android browser. The browser seems to recognized the "readonly" attribute (or readOnly via javascript), BUT the field does not actually become readonly. When you click it, the soft keyboard still appears and allows you to change the field.

I suppose that this is a bug in the Android browser. Can anyone come up with a clever alternative?

Comment: There was an [official bug submission](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3842), but the idea seems to be releasing a new OS version rather than a browser update. Supposedly, it is fixed in Froyo (2.2) which doesn't really help anyone expecting earlier clients to use their site.

No matter what I rigged up in the event handling, I couldn't keep Android from staying on that field and pulling up the keyboard. Android completely ignored this jQuery hack: `$("input[readonly=readonly]").unbind('focus').focus(function() { $("input.someOtherInput").focus(); });`

Answer (score 0):

I used a workaround - since I didn't need to actually edit in the input field (like you, I was popping a date picker), I changed to a span with similar styling. The code is kind of trivial once you have the trick, and it's really app specific so I don't have any really for you to see.